# Month grouping of invoices, based on conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of invoices that looks like this:

```
InvoiceDate InvoiceNumber   PaidDate    PayStatus   Amount
-----------------------------------------------------------
2012-1-23   1234            2012-02-28  Unpaid      1234
2012-2-01   2345            2012-03-12  Paid        23456
```

I need to GROUP these by (and take their monthly sums) certainly conditions.

I came up with a WHERE CLAUSE for only the current month.  The logic is like this.

- only extract invoices with invoice dates less than or equal to the last day of the previous month
- the 'lateness' should not exceed 90 days (lateness = diff(Period - (InvoiceDt + Terms)))
- take either unpaid PayStatus OR if it's marked as paid, ActualPaymentdt should be greater than or equal to the last day of the previous month
- if the day component of invoice date equals 1 AND it belongs to acct 4300, exclude it

This is only for the current month (which reports on the last day of the prev month).  I'm at a loss at how to do it for ALL MONTHS in the invoice table.

```
    -- only extract invoices with invoice dates less than or equal to the last day of the previous month
AND b.InvoiceDt <= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

    -- the 'lateness' should not exceed 90 days (lateness = diff(Period - (InvoiceDt + Terms)))
AND DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(day, ISNULL(b.Term, 0), b.InvoiceDt), DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) <= 90

    -- take either unpaid PayStatus OR if it's marked as paid, ActualPaymentdt should be greater than or equal to the last day of the previous month
AND (b.PayStatus = 'Unpaid' OR b.ActualPaymentDt >= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))

    -- if the day component of invoice date equals 1 AND it belongs to acct 4300, exclude it
AND NOT (b.AccountNumber = 4300 AND DAY(b.InvoiceDt) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join on another derived table that contains all months in the `invoices` table:

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, InvoiceDt), 0) as InvoiceMonth 
            FROM invoices) m
```

Then substitute `GETDATE()` with `m.InvoiceMonth`.

And don't forget to `GROUP BY m.InvoiceMonth` as well.